# php if logic calculation taking first part value only

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I have attempted a php if statement which should calculate values basis 2 paramteres:-

> Price
>
> Fuel - Petrol or Diesel or LPG or CNG

However - while executing the code - its only calculating the values when fuel type is not diesel

For instance when price is under 600000 and fuel is diesel - it still calculating .04 tax. Can you advise on whats wrong in the code. I have tried reworking - but could not get an answer

Below is Code

```
   <?php 
   $a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
   $b = $this->prodDet->v_fuel_type;

   if(($a < 600000) && ($b != 'Diesel'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.04*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
            }   
   else if(($a < 600000) && ($b == 'Diesel'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.05*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
            }

   else if((($a >= 600000) and ($a < 1000000)) and ($b != 'Diesel'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.07*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
            }

     else if((($a >= 600000) and ($a < 1000000)) and ($b == 'Diesel'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.0875*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
            }               

     else if((($a >= 1000000)) and ($b != 'Diesel'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.10*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
            }   
    else if((($a >= 1000000)) and ($b == 'Diesel'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.125*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
            }                           
    ?>
```

**Update**
I checked database value
in some fields there's a blank space after Diesel
For instance

Fuel Type = Diesel  (There's a blank space after diesel word)
Fuel Type = Petrol  (There's a blank space after diesel word)

when removed this blank space
Fuel Type = Diesel(No blank space after diesel word)
Fuel Type = Petrol(No blank space after Petrol word)

the calculation happening correctly

Also php logic changed a bit

```
else if((($a >= 1000000)) and ($b == 'Petrol'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.10*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
            }   
else if((($a >= 1000000)) and ($b == 'Diesel'))
            {           
                $calculatedtax = (.125*$a);
                echo($calculatedtax);
             }
```

Can someone advise how to correct php if statement logic - so that calculation can be performed by ignoring that black space in Fuel type

Comment: I've testet the code and it works for me correct. Try for testing hardcoded values for $a and $b.

Comment: var_dump("Diesel" == "diesel"); // bool(false)

Comment: @ Sectus - whats var_dump - how to integrate. What impact will it make

Comment: @ Joerg, @ Sectus - I found the error and updated the question. Its due to blank space after fuel type in database, can you advise how to correct the calculation now

Comment: did you try using `trim($b)` ?

Comment: @ Rxv - Thanks it works. Am able to get correct calculation now